# How to restore Ubuntu login screen after lubuntu install?

Tags: 13.10, login-screen

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed. I then installed lubuntu 13.10 (`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`) too. As a result the login screen has changed and I can no longer get an on screen keyboard.

How can I restore the login screen to the original Ubuntu default?

Comment: I have tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm but nothing happens.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` worked after I installed gdm.

Comment: lightDM.conf was empty so I opened it `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and added this: `[SeatDefaults]  greeter-session=unity-greeter  user-session=ubuntu` _Sorry but not for a lack of trying and despite reading (askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) I am unable to format the comment - it should be on 3 lines._ I then removed lightdm `sudo apt-get purge lightdm` and reinstalled it `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and after rebooting it worked. What a drama! And a waste of 2 hours of my life!

Comment: Please post your solutions as an answer and mark it as thé answer. This way future people (like me) will be able to see whether the question has been answered succesfully. Thank you.

Comment: For after installing xubuntu, `sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter` worked for me. Question on that [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/561465/how-to-remove-the-xubuntu-login-screen-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 10):

Since the OP is a bit lazy(!), I'm going to post the answer myself. Most of the times, the`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` solution doesn't work. You'll need to change the settings manually either by using `lightdm-set-defaults` or editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

- Open up `lightdm.conf`:

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
  ```
- You must have the following settings under `[SeatDefaults]`:

  ```
  user-session=ubuntu 
  greeter-session=unity-greeter
  ```
- Save and reboot.

Comment: Great, this was shoot right to the center. Thanks!

Comment: worked but the background image wasn't dynamic as before ...fixed this by reinstalling lightdm after doing what's in your answer. (To reinstall: `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`, it would ask some things during the uninstallation; chosse "ok" then "lightdm". If it gives you an error, uninstall again with the same command. Then reinstall; `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. Done :)

Comment: the file  `lightdm.conf` does not exist (Ubuntu 14.04.3). In installed lubuntu but now I cant to get back to a clean Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 2):

My login screen was changed after I installed KDE. Anyway, one possible solution (what worked for me because in my research I found others but they didn't work) was to uninstall and reinstall `lightdm`:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Of course, I had to specify what display manager I want (gdm, kdm or lightdm - after I broke my `lightdm` I used `gdm` as default). For this you have to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: Be very careful with the first command - it may try and remove loads of other packages as well

Answer (score 0):

My login screen was also changed to KDM after installing the KDE desktop on my Ubuntu 13.10 installation. The quickest solution for me was to run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And then you can choose for lightdm as a default instead of KDM.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to sudo apt-get purge or reinstall..

if this is after installing lubuntu just edit the lubuntu lubuntu.conf

```
cd /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d

sudo gedit 20-lubuntu.conf
```

then paste this to it:

```
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

thats work very well,

I read in this post: [How To Install LightDM 1.7.0 On Ubuntu 13.10/13.04/12.10 And Linux Mint 16/15/14](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-lightdm-1-7-0-on-ubuntu-13-1013-0412-10-and-linux-mint-161514/) and I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

but I disliked it, so I can't solve to my display manager default for Ubuntu, and after I did this:

Open lightdm.conf for editing in nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You must have the following settings under [SeatDefaults]:

```
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Save and reboot.

It's great, this works. Thanks for your support.