# Enable gnome login

Tags: gnome, login, default

So as I installed plasma desktop it obviously took over and now instead of desired login screen(picture) I see some KDE lightdm theme..would it be possible I could have the default Ubuntu 12.04 login screen(on picture-i can't post it bc of reputation but you know the one with grid and all)?

Comment: do this at the terminal: 

sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

And select gdm as default.

Comment: After you do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, you need to stop lightdm, and start gdm `sudo service lightdm stop`, and `sudo service gdm start`.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `unity-greeter` if it is missing.

and edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and change the line

```
greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter
```

to

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Save and exit and either restart `lightdm` with `sudo service lightdm restart` or reboot.