# How to remove the Xubuntu Login screen in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

I have recently installed Xubuntu on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.
So not a problem until I logged off, and i did not see my login screen but an ugly abnormal login screen (Xubuntu's Default)

Comment: Tell me if this helps: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-change-login-screen-background-remove-the-white-dots/ I've been trying to change gnome's back to unity's login.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
```

This will remove xfce's greeter and make sure the default Unity one is installed.

Comment: alright it worked but now it has taken my desktop background and set it as the default wallpaper for the login screen

Comment: What was it before? That's how the Unity greeter works, and it's the default in Ubuntu.

Comment: ok it was everybodys current background there was no default

Comment: I don't understand. Is your issue solved?

Comment: The login screen

Comment: @user283887 You aren't giving me enough information to understand what the rest of your problem is. Please be specific with your replies.

Comment: alot of comments... I had this issue after installing Xubuntu and `sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter` worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best (and right) way to achieve that is configuring plymouth by running and selecting `ubuntu-logo.plymouth`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Then you need to run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Alternative to the two steps above, you can simply remove the `plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo` package using `apt-get`, then the alternative will be chosen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore unity login screen after installing another desktop environment

Install unity-greeter and then make it default one by following these steps:

Type in the terminal:

sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

You'll enter a greeter configuration file. There find the line -

greeter-session= unity-greeter

If the line does not exit, add it. 
If instead of unity-greeter written anything else, edit it.