# Xubuntu and Ubuntu's display managers coexisting

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xfce

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Xfce via the 'xubuntu-desktop' package to try it out. After a couple days I decided to get back to Unity so I removed it and several other packages it came with.

The only thing that was left was the login display manager. When I boot the pc I get to the default Xubuntu display manager. However if I log out I get to Ubuntu's default display manager.

I removed light locker running "sudo apt-get purge light-locker*" and Xubuntu desktop following advice from here: [How to remove xubuntu-desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92084/how-to-remove-xubuntu-desktop).

I tried removing and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and lightdm but had no success.

I wish to get completely rid of the Xubuntu login display. Any ideas ?

Comment: Follow the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/561465/how-to-remove-the-xubuntu-login-screen-in-ubuntu-14-04/561492#561492

Comment: I dont have a lightdm.conf in that folder. Only: 'lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf', 'lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf' and 'users.conf'

Comment: sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install unity-greeter

Comment: @muzaffarhabibullayev awesome that worked! thanks :)