# How to remove the Xubuntu Login screen in Ubuntu 18.04 (and NOT 14.04)

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, login, lightdm, unity-greeter

Apart from Gnome I had / have Unity desktop in my Ubuntu 18.04. Later I installed Xubuntu over it. Change the desktop background with windows wallpaper. The same wallpaper was automatically taken by the xubuntu login screen. Later I removed xubuntu, But the unsophisticated login screen with more unpleasant windows wallpaper is still there.
Here, please note that After installing the Ubuntu 18.04 (with Gnome default) for the first time, I installed Unity (as it was my favorite) and the login screen changes into Unitiy (which is the best screen as per my opinion).
Recently, to get rid of Xubuntu login screen (and to check the desktop environment) I installed Ubuntu MATE. But still the login screen is the same xubuntu login screen.
I want to get rid of it. Either  Unity or MATE login screen will be fine.

In a similar post (for Ubuntu 14.04) ([How to remove the Xubuntu Login screen in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561465/how-to-remove-the-xubuntu-login-screen-in-ubuntu-14-04)) the below mentioned suggested command solved the issue

"sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install unity-greeter"

But presently Gnome is the default of Ubuntu and not the Unity. And I probably have lightdm as default. And I am a layman (non-technical person). Kindly help me with least technical jargon. If the above command is still applicable in toto or with some modification (like, 'install slick-greeter' instead of 'unity-greeter'), please confirm the same .

Presently it is like-
[similar to my left over xubuntu login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sjn1.jpg)

And I want it to be like-
[Unity login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNbd.png)

PS

Using this command- "sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter'' solved the issue upto 90%. Now I returned back the Unity Greeter which was already have installed there but in inactive state. After that from 'Login Window' app I reintroduce the 'Guest Session' option and change the desktop background to original Ubuntu 18.04 default wallpaper. But the wallpaper has been applied for the guest session (login screen) only. As soon as I choose myself as user the old (windows) wallpaper reappear in the login screen though it is still (my favourite) Unity Greeter interface. Right now I want to change my Greeter Wallpaper only. Please suggest. Kindly note that I am using 'Ubuntu Greeter' and 'lightdm' Desktop Manager.

Comment: You appear to be asking about the *greeter* wallpaper, which is changable and not related to the desktop being used (except installation often changes it for you). You haven't said what DM you're using (as many desktops use different ones, eg. `gdm3` is the default of Ubuntu now; are you using it?)

Comment: It is not limited to the wallpaper but the whole interface (I cannot remember what it is actually called, so I used the term 'login screen'). I am using lightdm. I also have Ubuntu Mate along with Unity and the Gnome.

Comment: using the command-