# Restoring Ubuntu 16.04 sign-on screen after removing LXDE / Lubuntu

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, lxde

After removing/purging LXDE and Lubuntu-desktop, I tried restoring my Ubuntu sign-on screen by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/a/421322/618307) `lightdm.conf`.  Unfortunately, the Ubuntu splash screen hung after selecting Ubuntu at the grub screen.

I additionally tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` before and after installing `gdm` but was unsuccessful.  Reinstalling lightdm also didn't do anything.

Does anyone know of a different way to restore the Ubuntu sign-on screen?  Thank you!

*Edit: For clarification, sign-on screen means where you choose account and enter password, not the splash screen.*

Comment: You can attempt to install the regular `ubuntu-desktop` pkg to get a login back. I am assuming that your boot is completing because you say that you were able to install things, which means you could access your ctrl-F2 terminal. You may even need to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop` to get it all back. Just an idea.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.  I was able to complete boot by using the virtual terminal to re-edit the config file (basically delete the entry I had made).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and then run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

**Edit 1:** As was stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install/421322#comment475385_371742) you need to add

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and then reinstall and purge `lightdm` completely.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

Comment: @KT12 Try [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install/421322#comment475385_371742)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you very much!
I think I omitted the line `[SeatDefaults]` when I first edited the lightdm.conf file.